# How do i delete a tkinter objects permanently (Not pack_forget etc...)

Tags: python, tkinter

I know about pack_forget()
I want to destroy a Button for e.g permanently.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this -

```
B1 = Button(root,text='Remove')

B1.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use destroy method for that  but be careful you wont be able too re add that

```
ButtonExample = Button(root, text='')
ButtonExample.destroy()
```